# Find files by not like mask

Tags: c#, regex, getfiles

I need to load files from a directory with search option. I created two search patterns, first I must find files begining with "Client" and without the "_delete" extension.

The second search must find files begining with "Client" and *with* extension "_delete".

I implemented test code, but did not find files.

```
string mask_not_like = @"Client*[^_delete\s].xlsx";
string mask = "Client*_delete.xlsx";

path1 = "c:\Client_Test.xlsx";
path2 = "c:\Client_Test_delete.xlsx";

var searchPattern1 = new Regex(mask_not_like, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var searchPattern2 = new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var files1 = Directory.GetFiles(path1).Where(f => searchPattern1.IsMatch(f));
var files2 = Directory.GetFiles(path1).Where(f => searchPattern2.IsMatch(f));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even bother with regex?

```
var clientFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "Client*.xlsx");
var clientFilesWithDelete = clientFiles.Where(clientFile => clientFile.EndsWith("_delete.xlsx"));
var clientFilesWithoutDelete = clientFiles.Except(clientFilesWithDelete);
```

Comment: Regex because I have mask properties in objects

Comment: @zrabzdn: None of your requirements call for a regex

Comment: Lame... i posted the same exact answer 7 minutes earlier :)

Comment: (:agreed, it was the obvious solution. I gave you a +1 in sympathy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first problem is that you're passing *file* paths to a method which expects a directory.

```
path1 = "c:\Client_Test.xlsx";
// path one is not a directory...
var files1 = Directory.GetFiles(path1).Where(f => searchPattern1.IsMatch(f));
```

[That should throw an `IOException` since `path1` is a file name.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Next, you're overcomplicating things. No regex is required (or warranted).

You have two cases; files which begin with "Client" and end in "_delete", and those which begin with "Client" and do not.  "Client" is common to both, so, just grab all files which begin with client, next find those that end in "_delete", and the rest are those which do not end in "_delete".

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "Client*.xlsx");
var endInDdelete = allFiles.Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == "._delete");
var doNotEndInDelete = allFiles.Except(endInDelete);
```

EDIT: I just noticed that you erroneously say that the extension is "_delete", when in reality, it's just the end of the file name.  So...

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "Client*.*");
var endInDdelete = allFiles.Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).EndsWith("_delete");
var doNotEndInDelete = allFiles.Except(endInDelete);
```